# Python how to "borrow" docstring from another class?

Tags: python, django

**Background**

I am using django-rest-swagger to display the API documentation, the official way for swagger is to use the docstring from the view.

**Purpose**

A lot of documentation as docstring are done in the `Model` class, so I would like to "borrow" the docstring from the `Model` class into the `APIModelView` class, without physically copying the docstring.

Eg.

```
class Model(models.Model):
  """
  Very comprehensive docstring...
  """

  field_1 = ...
  field_2 = ...


class APIModelView(ModelView):
  """
  <borrow from the model class>
  """
  model = Model
```

**Extension**

@Martijn Pieters' answer worked fine on class level docstring

I just realised swagger actually uses the instance method docstring, eg.

```
class APIModelView(ModelView):
      def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
          __doc__ = Model.__doc__
          ...
```

but above doesn't work...

Comment: It should be possible to subclass the `ModelView` metaclass, attach that to a subclass of `ModelView` and have the metaclass do exactly that for you, automatically. However, I can't actually find where you might have gotten `ModelView` from.

Comment: To the guy who downvoted this question, can you please specify the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `__doc__` attribute when creating the class; simply make that a copy of the original model:

```
class APIModelView(ModelView):
    __doc__ = Model.__doc__
    model = Model
```

Without an actual docstring on a class, any already-present `__doc__` attribute is retained.

Comment: Hi there, the class level docstring is setting fine now, thank you, do you know how to set the instance method docstring as well?

Comment: @JamesLin: 'instance method'? I'm not sure what you mean. Instances don't have a docstring; they inherit the `__doc__` attribute from their class.

Comment: @JamesLin: you'd set it as `self.__doc__`, not `__doc__` if you wanted to shadow the class attribute.

Comment: @JamesLin: however, are you *certain* that `django-rest-swagger` looks at view instances?

Comment: Yes Martijin, I am pretty sure it reads the docstring from each instance method to render the documentation. Anyway, both setting `__doc__` or `self.__doc__` just empties the docstring for the method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127018/discussion-between-james-lin-and-martijn-pieters).